# Services for Privatemsg module

Tags: services, 8, privatemsg

I am using [privatemsg services module](https://github.com/deminy/privatemsg_services) to create REST API of [privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) using [Services Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) in Drupal 7.

If I send GET request to this url : http://example.com/rest/privatemsg/ I get all messages including messages in Inbox and Sent. Is there any way to Get messages from Inbox and Sent separately ? OR is there any way i can differentiate messages from Inbox and Sent ?

Answer (score 0):

That resource has an optional [type parameter](https://github.com/deminy/privatemsg_services/blob/7.x-1.x/privatemsg_services.module#L75), so you should be able to get away with requesting:

http://example.com/rest/privatemsg/?type=inbox

Or ?type=sent, etc

Comment: I tried this URL http://example.com/rest/privatemsg?type=inbox but its still showing me all messages ?